# Handling clicks in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

So I am trying to implement a preferences menu in my app. I used the standard generated template in android studio. THe issue is that now I can't figure out how save the values the user specifies. I thought about using a click listener to determine when a user clicked a checkbox and then getting the actual value of the checkbox and saving that to sharedpreferences, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how use onClick in a preference activity?

OK, we seem to be on the right track about the system storing the values automatically, but whenever I try to reference them from my main class, it always returns null. Here is my code:

```
boolean trueorfalse = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity())
                .getBoolean("my_key", false)
```

;

Comment: My suggestion is to create your own activity and use Sharedpreferences to save the value.Earlier I had tried using preference activity and could not figure out how to add buttons on screen. I created a activity and saved values using sharedpreferences which worked for me.

Comment: So basically build my own activity that doesn't extend PreferenceActivity?

Comment: Exactly!! Use a regular activity and use these to save values `SharedPreferences prefs;SharedPreferences.Editor prefseditor;prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        prefseditor = prefs.edit();`

Comment: Doesn't that go against Google's design principles?

Comment: `prefseditor.putBoolean("silent_not", true).commit();` <---this to set values
`prefs.getBoolean("silent_not", true)`<-- this to get values

Comment: Don't there is any guidelines for this.

Comment: I get how to use shared preferences, its just that I can't figure out how to use a preferences menu onClick listener.

Comment: The suggestion given by Ranjith does not make any sense. There is a group of classes that does all that for you (PreferenceActivity and its friends), but you would suggesting basically reimplementing it from scratch as though it never existed. I don't understand why would anyone want to do that. The whole point of the PreferenceActivity is that it saves the values for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I assume you've already defined your Preferences in `res --> xml` and it looks something like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="my_key"
    android:summary="@string/desc_string"
    android:title="@string/title_string" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

As soon as the user checks or unchecks the CheckBox the systen will **automatically** create an entry in the default Preference-file which you can access like this:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    .getBoolean("my_key", false);
```

**But back to your initial question:** If you want to assign an `onClick-Listener` to your preference you have to do something like this:

```
    Preference myPreference = (Preference) findPreference("my_key");
    myPreference .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            // do something
        }
    });
```

***Note:*** *In this example it isn't a CheckBoxPreference, it's just a simple Preference*

Comment: OK, I thought that was the case, but whenever I access it, it always returns false, even if I have checked it. Is the system storing it correctly or am I just accessing it incorrectly?

Comment: Seems like your accessing it incorrectly. (Share the code and we'll see if we can find the problem) Nevertheless you can test if the system does the job correctly: Open your Preferences twice and see if the Checkbox keeps being checked.

Comment: Updated the main post with the code and the system is saving it, I checked by doing what you said

Comment: Thanks. And `"my_key"` is used in your Preference-XML like in my example?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same in my `SettingsMenu` by implementing `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`

```
   public class SettingsMenu extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        SharedPreferences menu_settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        menu_settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        ...
      }

      @Override
      public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        // check the checkboxes      


      }
    }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: So how did you determine if something had been clicked on?